# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

Tags: python

I trying to run the following script but encounter this error.

```
array.append([int(h[i:i + 2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)])
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Apparently you're trying to parse an empty string. What's the value of `h` ?

Comment: Also, is `array` actually a `list`?

Comment: @MosheSlavin How does that relate to this question?

Comment: @MosheSlavin What non-string are you talking about?

Comment: maybe can you show your variable 'h'

Comment: Actually i m a beginner and i am trying to understand this code.h is h = success.stdout.decode('utf-8').lstrip('#')

Comment: So if `h` is 4 characters or shorter, `h[4:6]` will be an empty string, and you can't convert an empty string to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse strings as numbers in hexadecimal, where each string is two characters from `h`. That means your string `h` needs to be long enough to have content for each of the substrings.

For instance, if `h` is `'1234'`, then

```
h[0:2] == '12'
h[2:4] == '34'
h[4:6] == ''
```

Your code can parse `'12'` and `'34'` as numbers in hex, but it can't parse `''`, so it would raise an exception.