# How to fix invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''?

Tags: python, hex, rgb

I have some hex strings (`splited_colors`) which I want to convert them into the colors. The splited_colors is a list with length of 221228 which its first row is like `splited_colors[1] = [['ab0232'],['0013aa'],['ac0102']]`. Also, I have another strings like '000000'.  Some of rows are converted but the others not. I checked that, all the hex strings are the same and I don't have any unusual hex string. What is this error refers to ?

```
RGB_colors_1 = []
for j in range (len(splited_colors)):        
    RGB_1 = tuple(int(splited_colors[j][0][k:k+2], 16) for k in (0, 2, 4))
    RGB_colors_1.append (RGB_1)
```

Comment: Please include what `spllited_colors` is; the issue is caused by the value of that variable which you have failed to include. Also, it should be "splitted", but that isn't the source of the error.

Comment: So you personally inspected all 211,228 strings to make certain that they were all properly formatted?  It seems that your program is telling you otherwise.  Have you tried catching the exceptions and printing out the lines that are failing?

Comment: You need to stop when you get that error and determine exactly what `splited_colors[j][0]` is.

Comment: New to Python? Your code is not much Pythonic, and "`splited_colors[1]`" is the second row. In any case: print the `splitted colour` and the RGB_1 in a file, and check when it fail. Is it possible you are not handling all cases (e.g. web use 3 hex digit colors also '#18c' which means `1188cc`). Or you may have empty data, or double quotes (common errors), just you should check what data fail. And if you do not find the cause, you can post it here (with the exact input which fail, and what do you expect as output (on such data).

Comment: @PaulCornelius I printed All the lines

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes I am new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link to see if it helps you with your question: [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293248/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-16). This exception can be called if you have  an empty string or any letter after f in the alphabet.

To find what string is causing the problem, I would add something like `print(j, RGB_1)` in your loop. This allows you to find the index of the hex that is causing the problem.